# Robocopy move from several folders into one destination

Tags: wildcard, robocopy

I have a source directory tree that looks like

```
source
--a1
  --foo.xml
  --bar.xml
--b2
  --baz.xml
--b3
```

and a destination that looks like

```
destination
--some_folder
```

I want to move all `*.xml` files from all folders in source to `some_folder` in destination using `robocopy`, in my example, the desired output should be:

```
destination
--some_folder
  --foo.xml
  --bar.xml
  --baz.xml
```

I seem to be unable to use wildcards in the source expression in robocopy.